# How to loop through a nested Object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the below object and I wanted to toggle all the boolen value inside of the object

```
{
    "2211284396232-5": {
        "2211284396232-5": false, 
        "644889430161": {
            "4812219518053": false, 
            "4812219518055": false,
            "4812219518063": false,
            "4812219518064": false,
            "4812219518069": false, 
            "644889430161": false
        }, 
    },
    
    "2211628865398-6": {
        "2211628865398-6": false, 
            "729563966440": {
                "5229922707373": false, 
                "729563966440": false
            }, 
    },
    
     "2212485574058-4": {
        "2212485574058-4": false, 
            "689399023594": {
                "5077186698704": false, 
                "5077186698712": false, 
                "689399023594": false
            }, 
    },
     
 }
```

I want to loop through this object and change all this false value to true value
How can I do this?

Comment: @UweKeim the approach you've linked will not work if there are more than 2 levels within the object

Comment: @AndrewParks It's still the same question. If you think an answer is missing, post your answer there and vote to close this question. It's not help helpful to have multiple same questions with different answers. One question with many different answers is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively examine each [key, value] entry in the object. You need to recurse when a property value is an object, and otherwise set the non-object properties to true.

```js
const data = {"2211284396232-5":{"2211284396232-5":false,"644889430161":{"4812219518053":false,"4812219518055":false,"4812219518063":false,"4812219518064":false,"4812219518069":false,"644889430161":false}},"2211628865398-6":{"2211628865398-6":false,"729563966440":{"5229922707373":false,"729563966440":false}},"2212485574058-4":{"2212485574058-4":false,"689399023594":{"5077186698704":false,"5077186698712":false,"689399023594":false}}}

const f = obj => Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) =>
  typeof v === 'object' ? [k, f(v)] : obj[k] = true)

f(data)
console.log(data)
```

If you want to toggle the values instead of setting them to true, you can do this:

```js
const data = {"2211284396232-5":{"2211284396232-5":false,"644889430161":{"4812219518053":false,"4812219518055":false,"4812219518063":false,"4812219518064":false,"4812219518069":false,"644889430161":false}},"2211628865398-6":{"2211628865398-6":false,"729563966440":{"5229922707373":false,"729563966440":false}},"2212485574058-4":{"2212485574058-4":false,"689399023594":{"5077186698704":false,"5077186698712":false,"689399023594":false}}}

const f = obj => Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) =>
  typeof v === 'object' ? [k, f(v)] : obj[k] = !obj[k])

f(data)
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Thanks alot bro, actually i wanted to toggle the value, you've just done it all. Thanks one again